# using "fo inline" and keep together within line make the text go out of the box and never go to the next line

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo, apache-fop

```
<xsl:for-each select="../div">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@class='champLibre'">
      <fo:inline keep-with-next.within-line="always" >
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      </fo:inline> 
      <fo:inline  border-bottom-style="dotted"  border-bottom-color="#000"
            border-bottom-width="1pt"><xsl:value-of select="div/text()"/>
          <xsl:text>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</xsl:text>
      </fo:inline> 
    </xsl:when>
```

I want to align the block (the content of the div + some text) in the same line, so that when it comes to the end of line the block which contains div+some text must go to the next line if there is no enough space for both div + some text.

However, I get something like this:

```
First line:  .... some 
Second line: words:.....
```

What I want is:

```
First line:  .... 
Second line: some words:...
```

[image: without using keep]

[image: after using keep together within line]

Comment: The title says `keep-together`, but your example has `keep-with-next`: which one are you really using?

Comment: i have tried to use both of them but i have always the same problem, the text is in the same line but it will never go to the second line and it goes out of the page i will join a sreenshot

Answer (score 1):

The `fo:inline` (currently) has to be kept with what comes next in the line, and what comes next is an `fo:inline` that ends with a non-breaking space.  You haven't left anywhere for the line to break.

Try putting each pair into a separate `fo:block`:

```
<xsl:for-each select="../div">
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="@class='champLibre'">
      <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        <fo:inline  border-bottom-style="dotted"  border-bottom-color="#000"
            border-bottom-width="1pt">
          <xsl:value-of select="div/text()"/>
          <xsl:text>&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;</xsl:text>
      </fo:block> 
    </xsl:when>
```

Comment: I don't understand your comment, but another solution would be to put a space or even a zero-width space after the last non-breaking space.

Comment: You could instead set the width of your second `fo:inline`, e.g., `<fo:inline width="4em">`, and get rid of the non-breaking spaces.

Comment: if there is no value inside fo:inline the width is not applied i have already put it, i should instead use block-container and in this case i wont have the possibility to align text ...